# Make words move in real time in ruby on in the terminal

Tags: ruby

Is there a way words move/animate letters moving in time? For example:

```
LOVEX
```

I want to X to move between the other letters like.

```
LOVXE
LOXVE
LXOVE
```

but with one condition: I don't want to output new lines or entering new words, I want it to be on the same word in a single line so it looks kind of like a gif.

Comment: Hi Ernani, welcome to SO. To understand the question, you should describe what kind of environment you are looking at. For instance: Do you want to do this on the command line or as a animated picture.

Comment: Answering the question stated: yes, there is a way to make it happen. One just needs to write a code to accomplish the task.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to just print on the terminal this should work.  Write this in a file called `lovex.rb`

```
# lovex.rb
love = 'LOVE'
print love
[*0..4].reverse.each do |i|
  sleep 1
  love = love.gsub('X','')
  love.insert(i, 'X')
  print "\r"
  if i > 0
    print love
  else
    print 'LOVE'
  end
end
```

Then in your terminal just run:

```
ruby lovex.rb
```

Comment: I didn't know about `print "\r"`. That's interesting.

Comment: What specifically does `\r` do? It's hard to Google even when searching for "backslash r"

Comment: @Matt it's linux "carriage return" see  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html  so it will return to beginning but without a new line.

Comment: In the midst of time typewriters evolved into [teleprinters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) which in turn were modified to provide a rudamentary input-output device for early computers. For output, after each line was printed it was necessary--as on a typewriter--to move the carriage back to the beginning of the line (carriage return) and also to rotate the platen (line feed) so that the next line would not overprint the last one.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken @lacostenycoder's idea and implemented it in a slightly different way.

```
def word_line_boogie(word, ntimes, delay)
  enum = (0.upto(word.size)).map do |i|
    ("\r"+word.dup).insert(-i-1,'X')
  end.cycle
  ntimes.times do
    print enum.next
    sleep delay
  end
end
```

```
word_line_boogie('LOVE', 10, 1)
```

displays

```
LOVEX
LOVXE
LOXVE
LXOVE
XLOVE
LOVEX
LOVXE
LOXVE
LXOVE
XLOVE
```

except all but the first word is overwrites the previous one.

For `word = 'LOVE'`,

```
enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["\rLOVEX", "\rLOVXE", "\rLOXVE",
  #                  "\rLXOVE", "\rXLOVE"]:cycle>
10.times.map { enum.next }
  #=> ["\rLOVEX", "\rLOVXE", "\rLOXVE", "\rLXOVE", "\rXLOVE",
  #    "\rLOVEX", "\rLOVXE", "\rLOXVE", "\rLXOVE", "\rXLOVE"]
```

Comment: Nice refactor!  However I would have probably added an option for the letter to "shuffle" in place of `X` and named the method `word_line_dance` :)

Comment: @lacostenycoder, thanks for the suggestions. I renamed the method.

Comment: Also, I could not figure out why adding `puts "\rLOVE"` to the end of the script leaves `LOVEE` on the line.  Any clue?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, are you sure? If `def a; print "\rcat"; puts "\rdog"; end`, `a` prints `"cat"` then overprints `"dog"`, followed by a newline.

Comment: @lacostenycoder, instead of `puts "\rLOVE"` as the last line, try `puts "\rQ"`. After the loop ends the line is seen to be `"LOVEE"`. Now `puts "\rQ"` is executed. The carriage return causes the write pointer to move to the beginning of the same line. It does not, however, erase what is displayed on the line. Next, `"Q"` is displayed at the beginning of the line, overwritting `"L"`, causing `"QOVEE"` to appear. Lastly a newline, or *line feed*, `"\n"` causes the display pointer to move to the next line and (unlike its affect on a teleprinter) also performs a carriage return.